# Did J. Robert Oppenheimer ever play chess?

Tags: physics, chess

There is an infamous chess game between Einstein and Oppenheimer that has zero evidence of having happened (and that appears every time I try to look something about it and now even the comments of this question are about that). Much has been said about Einstein and his relation to chess, but what about Oppenheimer? Do we have any evidence that he ever played chess? This information does not appear in biographies like *American Prometheus*.

Comment: FWIW, I'd find it hard to believe the statement that he *never* played. I don't know a lot of people today who have never played it. However, getting any further information is proving quite difficult due to the apocryphal story of the Einstein match washing out any other search results.

Comment: For person proficient in math and science to not play chess would be extremely unusual.

Comment: It's remarkably easy to find other physicists who crossed paths with him and were avid chess players for example https://pubs.aip.org/physicstoday/article/56/12/87/632224 and https://pubs.aip.org/physicstoday/article/61/11/72/413157/Willis-Eugene-Lamb-Jr. So far I see no evidence that Oppenheimer played with any of them.

Comment: Thanks to the answer from Anonymous I now see [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_versus_Oppenheimer) about the game. It does have a lot of relevant references but nothing directly about the general plausibly that Oppenheimer played.

Comment: It's difficult to find reputable evidence that Oppenheimer played chess or that he played a game with Einstein. There are websites [claiming such a game occurred](https://www.chess.com/blog/ThummimS/albert-einstein-vs-j-robert-oppenheimer). [Scientific American](https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/robert-oppenheimer-documentary/), states: "Oppenheimer was a chess grand master in a game of checkers. He was looking to checkmate the other guy's king by trapping his queen, maneuvering around his bishops and sidestepping his knights, ..." ...

Comment: ... "... whereas his opponent was merely planning to jump his pieces and have himself kinged.". The issues I have with that statement is checkers & checkers doesn't have queens or bishops. It's as if the author didn't know what they were writing about.

Comment: According to [Einstein versus Oppenheimer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_versus_Oppenheimer), "There is no conclusive evidence that Albert Einstein and J. Robert Oppenheimer ever played chess together". Also, "The earliest known source for the game is the 1959 book Freude am Schach by Gerhard Henschel, but provides no date or venue. The 1967 French Dictionaire des echecs, cites Henschel's book but refers to the chess game in conditional tense. Henschels book is also known for containing other unverified chess games from other famous figures like Joseph Stalin or Leo Tolstoy."

Comment: @fred thanks for this information but the question is not about the Einstein vs Oppie chess game but about Oppenheimer uniquely

Comment: @Fred going by your quotes, it reads as an analogy: Oppenheimer was playing chess while those around him were playing a much simpler game. But neither was really playing with chessmen nor draughts pieces, but with real humans. Checking the SciAm article, the first paragraph confirms that it's an analogy, and not an original one.